# std::out_of_range error and trying to get string between two delimeter

Tags: c++, string

As I mentioned in the title, I want to get the string value between 2 delimiters. Inside the array, the first string may not include the start delimiter I'm looking for, but the second string may as well. As in the example. The ending delimiter can be in the last string of the array. I want to get the 1st string and the last string. By paying attention to delimiters, of course.

If we look at the array I created below, the output I want to get is as follows: "KKKAAAAAADDD"

But the error i get while running the code is as follows;

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
> what():  basic_string::substr: __pos (which is 4294967295) >
> this->size() (which is 13)

```
std::string hex[4] = { "ZZZZZZZZZZZ07", "06KKK","AAAAAA", "DDD07" };

string startDEL = "06";
string stopDEL =  "07";

for(int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++)
{
    unsigned firstLim = hex[i].find(startDEL);
    unsigned lastLim = hex[i].find(stopDEL);

    string strNew = hex[i].substr (firstLim,lastLim);

    strNew = strNew.substr(firstLim + startDEL.size());

    std::cout << strNew << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: You lost me at *"Inside the array"*. What array? At that point, you had mentioned "the string value" and "2 delimiters". Suddenly having an array involved is at best confusing. (At worst, it could indicate that even you do not know what is supposed to happen.) Try rewriting your first paragraph to better establish the context for your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep it simple concatenate the strings before calling `find`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <numeric>

std::string sub_between(const std::string& start,const std::string& stop,const std::string& input){
    // try to find start
    auto start_index = input.find(start);
    // was it found?
    if (start_index != std::string::npos) {
        // try to find stop, starting after the start delimiter
        auto stop_index = input.find(stop,start_index+start.size());
        // was it found?
        if (stop_index != std::string::npos){
            // return substring
            return {input.begin() + start_index+start.size(), input.begin() + stop_index};
        }
    }
    // otherwise return empty string
    return {};
}

int main() {
    std::string hex[4] = { "ZZZZZZZZZZZ07", "06KKK","AAAAAA", "DDD07" };

    std::string startDEL = "06";
    std::string stopDEL =  "07";

    std::string concat = std::accumulate(std::begin(hex),std::end(hex),std::string(""));
    std::cout << sub_between(startDEL,stopDEL,concat);       
}
```

In your code you try to find both `startDEL` and `stopDEL` in the same array element and then use the results to call `substr` without checking if the delimiters were actually found. Your approach cannot work that way, because the delimiters are not in the same element. You would have to first search for `startDEL` only, then search for `stopDEL`, handle the case when they aren't found to continue with the next element until you find them. Then concatenate the elements, using substrings of the first and last element that contain the delimiters.

Answer (score 3):

With

```
unsigned firstLim = hex[i].find(startDEL);
unsigned lastLim = hex[i].find(stopDEL);

string strNew = hex[i].substr (firstLim,lastLim);
```

`firstLim` will be equal to `std::string::npos` if `startDEL` is not found.  `std::string::npos` is going to larger then the `size()` of `hex[i]`, so `substr` will throw an exception for that.

You are going to need to add logic on how to handle when a sub string cannot be found.